# Sorting filtered array alphabetically / VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sorting, vuejs2

I have a json file with a column named "Input1" - I filter over this function and check if there are any duplicates in there. So without my "sort" it works well - but exactly here is my problem.. my sort function is not working.. but I dont know where the problem is..

My function:

```
computed: {
    filterInput1: function() {
      var array = this.json.map((input) => input.Input1);
      return array
        .filter((input, index) => array.indexOf(input) == index) 
        .sort((a, b) => {
          if(a.Input1 < b.Input1)
            return -1;
          if(a.Input1> b.Input1)
            return 1;
          return 0;    
        })
        .map((input) => {return {text: input, value: input}; }); 
    },
```

my json:

```
data() {
  return {
    json: [
      { "Test1": 111, "Input1": "Hello" },
      { "Test2": 222, "Input1": "Goodbye" },
      { "Test3": 333, "Input1": "Ciao" },
      { "Test4": 444, "Input1": "Goodbye"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using `a.Input1` when you previously mapped from objects to just the property `.map((input) => input.Input1)`? Also, "not working" is not a sufficient error description.

Comment: I try to filter if one element is higher ranked than the other.. - I wrote 'not working' because I got no error message.. it's just not filter my array alphabetically.. I can't get you an error description..

Comment: What is the expected output? Please add that as part of question.

Comment: But thank You - that was the problem that Im using ```a.Input1``` - thank You!